# CArt Throb Price by Member Group PLUS price modifier

Tags: cartthrob

Not sure if this is even possible but worth asking.

I am using the Price by Member Group fieldtype to offer a different price for a specific member group.

But what if I have a price modifier. ie: small/medium/large as well.

So the base Price is $50
The discounted member group the base price is $25

And if you order large you add $30 to the product for global and you add $15 if you order large  and are in the discounted member group.

This doesn't seem possible based on what I can see.

Comment: did you figure this out? I am using Matrix for options, and need different prices for different member groups.

Comment: I'm using the multi_add_to_cart_form tag, and within this is allow_user_price="yes" and you can pass the price as a hidden field which modifies it, <input type="hidden" name="price[{row_id}]" value="{new_price_here}" />. I am going to try to write a plugin to get the correct price from another Matrix field for the other member groups. I think the standard add to cart tag also allows a price to be modified.